# "Sending off a balloon": verb or noun?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, gerunds, present-participles, ing

[image]

> Agnes suggested **sending off** a balloon with a message to Jenny.

The phrase *sending off* puzzles me. I know it’s a verb phrase, but I don’t understand why it ends on *-ing*. Is it a noun or a verb?

I've looked at *-ing* words and spent some time thinking about how they are used. Normally, we use them as verbs with a form of *to be*, but there is no *am* or *is* here. When you Google "sending off", you get something about rugby, or it shows you *send-off*. But those are probably not the same thing. It's hard to find the right words to search for. I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: For future questions you can also consider https://ell.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 8):

This form of the verb is conventionally called a **gerund**. From the outside, a gerund works partly like a noun, because it can be the object of a verb, just like a normal noun:

> Agnes suggested **sending off a balloon**.
>
> Agnes suggested **group therapy**.

Both the gerund phrase and the normal noun phrase have the same function in the main clause, that of an object.

But from the inside, gerunds are somewhat like (main) verbs. In this case, the gerund has a (prepositional) object of itself, which is what verbs normally do:

> sending off **a balloon**
>
> He sends off **a balloon**.

Comment: Right, *sending* is a verb, but that entire non-finite verb phrase it’s heading is the object of the main (finite) verb, *suggested*. The reason people are always confused about these is because they have never been taught actual syntactic roles only parts of speech, and you can’t resolve paradoxes until you go to a higher level of analysis. When they find themselves forced to try to call the multiword phrase a “noun” because as a syntactic constituent it’s playing the same role as a noun would, they get all tangled up. But phrases aren’t parts of speech, only single words are.

Comment: @tchrist♦: But, when a phrase can be substituted for a single word without changing the predicate frame, that means they work similarly in the same context. // I was trying to solve the paradox by the (widely accepted) analysis of a gerund as both noun-like and verb-like at the same time, one its external face, the other its internal.

Comment: You did fine. I just resist the absurd reduction that leads people to call verbs nouns just because they're objects.

Comment: @tchrist♦: Words are just words.

Comment: Wouldn't "sending" technically be a PARTICIPLE part of a verb phrase? From the CMS: "*Because participles and gerunds both derive from verbs, the difference between them depends on their function. A participle is used as a modifier {the **running** water} or as part of a verb phrase {the meter **is running**}; it can be modified only by an adverb {the **swiftly** running water}. A gerund is used as a noun {**running is** great exercise}; it can be modified only by an adjective {**sporadic running and walking** makes for a great workout}.*" Here, "sending" cannot be modified by an adjective.

Comment: Also from the CMS: " *[A] present participle is always modified (if at all) by an adverb, whether the participle serves as a verb {**she’s parking** the car **now**}, an adjective {I’ll be looking for **a parking place**}, or an adverb {**finally parking**, we saw that the store had already closed}. It is traditionally considered a linguistic fault (a fused participle) to use a nonpossessive noun or pronoun with a gerund.*"

Comment: @TheWordsmith: Some scholars use somewhat different definitions of gerund and participle. The beginning of your source is conventional. But the part where gerunds can only be modified by adjectives is not conventional. Some distinguish between *three* kinds of *-ing* forms rather than two, which they may call participle, gerund, noun. In that system, however, it is *-ing* nouns that can be modified only by adjectives, and gerunds that cannot (but which instead have verbal arguments, such as objects and prepositional phrases). So this would seem to be a mistake in the CMS. ...

Comment: Its discussion of present participles is again unconventional in a way that I cannot explain. The sentence *"she's parking the car now"* would normally be analysed thus. The verbal phrase is *is parking*, which does indeed include a present participle. The object of the verbal phrase is *the car*. The adverb *now* modifies either the verbal phrase, or the whole predicate including *the car*, but not just the participle. Generally, participles are *-ing* forms that function like adjectives from the outside and verbs from the inside, as gerunds are *-ing* forms that function like nouns. ...

Comment: So participles can indeed generally be modified by adverbs (*"she was slowing parking her car"*), but not in that example. // In *"a parking space"*, the *-ing* form is no participle at all. Cf. the following transformation. *I am parking* (verbal phrase) => *the parking woman* (attributive participle): it is the noun that is doing the parking, the woman. When you use a participle attributively (with a noun rather than inside a verbal phrase with *be/have*), the subject from before the transformation becomes the noun after. ...

Comment: Now consider *"the parking space"*. Is it the space that's parking? No. Therefore, it is no participle. It is a gerund instead, "the action of parking"; but the gerund is used like an adjective here, as it is possible to do with nouns in English. *A large space, a car space, a parking space.* A car space (used in Australia for a parking space) is a space related to cars. A parking space is a space related to (the action of) parking, not a space that is parking. ...

Comment: Their example of an adverbial participle is usually called a predicative participle, being structured liked an adjective but functioning semantically quite like an adverb. (Adjectives can also be predicative, e.g. "*she arrived **first**; he left **sad** that he had been rejected*"). // In summary, it is best to think of a participle as being like an adjective from the outside, but a verb from the inside; a gerund, like a noun from the outside, verb from the inside. If you can replace it with an **adjective** and the structure of the main clause doesn't change much, it was a **participle**.

Comment: P.S. Where I said *"I am parking"*, it would have been better to say *"the woman is parking"*. Then the transformation with intact meaning is easier to see: *"the woman is parking"* (participle in verbal phrase with *is*) => *"the parking woman"* (attributive participle modifying the noun *woman*). Somewhat similar constructions. But a parking woman and a parking space are very different constructions, one having a participle, the other a gerund (unless the space is doing parking, which would be nonsense). P.P.S. My apologies for the word wall!

Comment: @Cerberus I like those who try to be un-patronizingly informative. Although, I have a question on what you said. Why do you consider “parking” in “the parking space” to be a gerund? “Parking” is *describing* what type of space that space is, and adjectives are the modifiers that describe nouns. (In this case, the space.) Also, I highly doubt the *Chicago Manual of Style* made such a mistake, especially since this rule was mentioned more than once...

Comment: @Cerberus More from the CMS, 17th edition: “*As nouns, gerunds are modified by adjectives {**double-parking** is prohibited}, including possessive nouns and pronouns {**Critt’s parking** can be hazardous to pedestrians}.*”

Comment: @Cerberus Also from the CMS: “*A gerund is a present participle used as a noun. It is not limited by person, number, or mood. Being a noun, the gerund can be used as (1) the subject of a verb {**complaining** about it won’t help}; (2) the object of a verb {I don’t like your **cooking**}; (3) a predicate nominative or complement {his favorite pastime is **sleeping**}; or (4) the object of a preposition {reduce erosion by **terracing** the fields}. In some sentences, a gerund may substitute for an infinitive.*” There is another sentence, but I have reached my word limit.

Answer (score 0):

It’s traditionally considered a **verbal noun**.  However, linguists don’t necessarily think of “noun” and “verb” as mutually-exclusive categories, and this is a good example why. They talk about the grammatical function of a word.

In this instance, I think *sending off* looks, walks and quacks more like a verb.  Compare: “Agnes suggested **we send** off a balloon with a message to Jenny.”  In this example, *send* is the main verb of a subordinate clause, and it’s the clause that is the direct object of *suggested*.

However, we can easily think of examples where *sending off* functions like a noun. (“The **sending off** was difficult.”)

Comment: There is an elliptical *that*: *"Agnes suggested [that] we send off a balloon with a message to Jenny."* So, yes, *send* is indeed a verb there (a subjunctive) even from the outside, and of course also from the inside. It was necessary to add a subject (*we*) for the subordinate clause to work. But now change the main verb such that there could be no elliptical *that*: "*Agnes hated sending off a balloon."* That construction isn't possible any more. You can replace it only with a normal noun (*"she hated air pollution"*) or an infinitive (*"she hated to send a balloon"*): both noun-ish.

Comment: I’m not seeing a difference: “Agnes hated that we **sent/would send/were sending** off a balloon.” “Agnes hates that we **have sent/are sending/will send** off a balloon.” Only the simple present tense is ruled out in that context.

Comment: @Cerberus In fact, I think the only problem with your example is the “a” in front of “balloon.”  “*Agnes hates that we send off balloons,*” works just fine, but means that we send off balloons repeatedly. Adding an indefinite article makes it a single balloon, one time, so we’d instead say, “*Alice hates that we **are sending** off **a** balloon.*” Even “*Alice hates that we send off a balloon on Fridays,*” works just fine.